# What are all the keyboard shortcuts for this site?

Tags: support

What are the list of keyboard shortcuts you can use on this site? I know I can get each shortcut by hovering my mouse over the buttons above the answer text area but I was wondering if there's a list somewhere.

*Just for clarification's sake I'm not talking about the [markdown editing help page](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of keyboard-shortcuts for the buttons listed above the answer's text area *(in their order of appearance)* are as follows:

**Bold** = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

*Italics* = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

[Hyperlink](http://askubuntu.com) = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

> Blockquote = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

`Code Tags` = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Image[image] = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

1. Ordered list = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

- Unordered list = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

### Heading = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Horizontal Rule = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

---

Undo = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Redo = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget the wonderful user script which gives you MOAR KEYBOARD SHORTCUTS!!

https://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts